# klusta IPython Qt error

Tags: ipython, anaconda

```
(klusta)patelj65@Satchmo:~/klusta$ klustaviewa
/home/patelj65/anaconda3/envs/klusta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/qt.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.qt` package has been deprecated. You should import from qtconsole instead.
  "You should import from qtconsole instead.", ShimWarning)
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40801) with this library (version 0x40805)
Aborted (core dumped)
```